# split function to change order

Tags: ldap

i used a methode to get treepath i get it like this 
[dc=example,dc=com,ou=Usres] and i need to make it look like this
ou=Usres,dc=example,dc=com
so i tried this methode to change the order

```
public static String changeString(String old)
{
    old = old.replace('[', ' ');
    old = old.replace(']', ' ');
    old.trim();
    String array[] = old.split(",");
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
        if(i != 1)
        result +=","+ array[array.length-i];
        else
        result += array[array.length-i];    

    }
```

but i get the like this ou=Usres,dc=com,dc=example
how can i do to change only the position of ou=users

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, I would suggest you use the [UnboundID SDK](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/index.html). Using the [DN class](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/DN.html), you can break down the items with public RDN[] getRDNs(), which returns a RDN[]

Then you could simply reorder the RDN[] and then create the new DN with DN(RDN... rdns).

Comment: thank's for you are answer but  i'am already using jndi is there any way to get the new dn with it !